# permission denied: GetObject("IIS://" & strServer & "/w3svc/4/ROOT")

Tags: vba, iis-7

please help. I have my code in visual basic. Error permission denied GetObject("IIS://loclahost/w3svc/4/ROOT")

```
    Set wServer = GetObject("IIS://loclahost/w3svc/4")
    Set wRoot = GetObject("IIS://loclahost/w3svc/4/ROOT") 'Get the root web
    Set wNew = wRoot.Create("IIsWebVirtualDir", strWebName) 'Create a new web off the root

    ''Create New App
    wNew.AppCreate True
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could post more details information about your requirement.

Do you run this code in your web application which hosted on the IIS?

It seems that your application pool doesn't have the enough permission to get the IIS web site information.

I suggest you could try to modify the application pool identity permission to local system, if you want to create or modify the IIS setting.

Details, you could refer to below steps:

1.In IIS Manager, select Application Pools.

2.From the list of application pools, right-click your application pool and select Advanced Settings.

3.In the Process Model section, change the identity property from ApplicationPoolIdentity to localsystem, and click OK.